# flutter how to add button to carousel

Tags: flutter

I was trying to add floating button to carouselSlider but when i slide carousel i get that pixelerror any idea to fix it ?[image]

```
CarouselSlider(
                  height: 540,
                  initialPage: 0,
                  autoPlay: false,
                  reverse: false,
                  items: imgList.map((imgUrl) {
                    return Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.network(
                                imgUrl,
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:13.0),
                                child: FloatingActionButton(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  child:icon,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      icon = Icon(Icons.favorite);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your image and FAB in a Stack Widget with a bottom center alignement like this

```
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'imgUrl',
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () => print,
            )
          ],
        ),
```